# What is the difference between: Field and Property and Auto-implemented property

Tags: c#, .net, class, properties, field

As a fresher, I am trying to learn C# online. I came across property and field concept and I got this doubt. The following two code snippets give the same output, so what is the difference. Please explain in easy words.

```
{
    class Student
    {
        // Auto-implemented Properties  
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
        public string Email;
    }
    class AutoImplementedProperty
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            // Setting properties  
            student.ID = 101;
            student.Name = "Rahul Kumar";
            student.Email = "rahul@example.com";
            // Getting properties  
            Console.WriteLine(student.ID);
            Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(student.Email);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace CSharpFeatures
{
    class Student
    {
        // Auto-implemented Properties  
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
    class AutoImplementedProperty
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            // Setting properties  
            student.ID = 101;
            student.Name = "Rahul Kumar";
            student.Email = "rahul@example.com";
            // Getting properties  
            Console.WriteLine(student.ID);
            Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(student.Email);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```